# Having both gnome and kde without the need to switch between them

Tags: gnome, kde

Is it possible to install and run both gnome and kde on Ubuntu and enjoy the best of both worlds without having to switch between them?

Comment: It would be nice if those who vote down a question could explain it in a comment. This is a perfectly legitimate question about how to get a particular type of Ubuntu installation.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I think the question could be greatly improved if the poster specified what would be "the best of both worlds" to him. Is he just looking to run KDE applications in the Gnome environment? Or is he wanting the Unity overlay dash thing with the KDE taskbar/launcher and desktop widgets?

Answer (score 4):

That depends what specifically you mean.

Of course, you can install both environments, the packages themselves are not mutually exclusive. You can start with one environment, and you will be able to run the programs from the other. For example, runnning KDE programs with Gnome is not a problem.

However, only one environment would be responsible for actually managing your desktop.

Answer (score 2):

you can .

```
ctrl+alt+f2
```

after you must login

```
startx -- :2
```

it will be other desktop with ctrl+alt+f8 if you want first you will press ctrl+alt+f7

Comment: Running two x sessions each with it's own desktop manager?  Interesting, Perhaps a good way to compare and choose between them.